# How can I get the human name from the machine name for an extension?

Tags: 10

I want to get the human name from the machine name for an extension (i.e. a module or a theme).

I know that I can do this for a *module* by this call:

```
$human_name = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getName('automated_cron');
```

This will return the human name for core **Automated Cron** module.

To do the same thing for a theme, I can invoke the service `'extension.list.theme'`.

Is there something that will provide this information and not care whether the extension is a module or a theme?

In my current implementation, I use this workaround:

```
$extension_name = 'automated_cron';
if (\Drupal::service('module_handler')->moduleExists($extension_name)) {
  $human_name = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->getName($extension_name);
}
else {
  $human_name = \Drupal::service('extension.list.theme')->getName($extension_name);
}
dpm($hunan_name, 'human name');
```

Is there a simpler way to get the desired result (i.e. without using an if-test)?

Comment: The module and theme lists are maintained in different service instances. I don't think there is a single service for querying both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Both [extension.list.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/extension.list.theme/10.0.x) and [extension.list.theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/extension.list.module/10.0.x) services extends `ExtensionList` to get human name.

So you can replace your `if` statement by this one :

```php
$name = 'automated_cron';
$extension = \Drupal::service('extension.list.module');
$human_name = ($extension->exists($name)) ? $extension->getName($name) : '';
```

Some useful sources :

- [ThemeExtensionList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ThemeExtensionList.php/class/ThemeExtensionList/10)
- [ModuleExtensionList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleExtensionList.php/class/ModuleExtensionList/10)
- [ExtensionList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ExtensionList.php/class/ExtensionList/10)